# No Suitable Driver found for JDBC-Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am building a project using **"Maven".**
In the Pom.xml i have added dependency for Postgresql and it is downloaded (as required) and is **present in the Project's libs/ folder**.

Now i have made a connection to it in my java file as follows :

```
static String userid="postgres", password = "myPassword";
static String url = "jdbc:postgresql:coredb_jfeed6";
static Connection con;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userid, password);
```

Where "coredb_jfeed6" is my database name.

There is no compile time error. But at runtime it produces the following error :

```
   Exception stack is:
    1. No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql:coredb_jfeed6 (java.sql.SQLException)
    java.sql.DriverManager:640 (null)
    Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql:coredb_jfeed6
    (org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:80 (null)

Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql:coredb_jfeed6
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:640)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
```

Could anyone please help me regarding this.?

Comment: Any help would be deeply appreciated.?. i have actually spent much time in this and am getting quite frustrated. please help me.

Comment: the postgres-sql-driver is present in your libs folder, but is it in your classpath when you execute your program? it seems like it is not. how are you executing your program? in eclipse? outside eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out.

Its a **BUG** in Mule 3.1.2.

Its like "When an external library is to be searched, then Mule looks it in projects/lib folder. But this does not hold true for **All the Database related Libraries** like postgresql library" . So we need to put it in ***mule/user/lib*** folder for it to Work Correctly.